# Sub Panel in detached 10x10 bldg(welding shed)

Tags: electrical-panel

Main bldg with 200a service. Detached 10x10 welding shed 40' away. Ran #6 (hot, hot, neutral, and #8 ground) in conduit from main bldg to shed for 60a service. Will have 60a breaker in main bldg panel feeding a 12 circuit sub panel with 60a main breaker for disconnect since we have more than 6 circuits. Will have #6 bare copper ground to two 8' ground rod outside bldg. Installed grounding bar in Panel and is not bonded.

Inside welding shed will have two 220v circuits using 6/3 on 50a breakers. Remaining 6 circuits are 12/2 for 110v lighting and outlets. (two 20a GFCI circuits, one dedicated 20a non-GFCI for small AC window unit, one dedicated 20a 120v for welder, one dedicated 15a for LED inside lighting, and one dedicated 20a for outside GFCI outlet.

This is not a commercial welding setup and only ONE of the three welders will ever be used at any given time.

Am I on the right track?

Any input is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Richard

Comment: I hope you mean 12 space and not 12 circuit.  12 "circuit" is a lie because it relies on double-stuff breakers.  So many circuits these days need AFCI/GFCI protection and those don't come in double-stuff.

Comment: Yes, 12 space. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. What is important is the duty cycle of your individual welders. NEC Article 630 is all about welders including there duty cycles.

The duty cycle is determined by what type of welding you are going to be doing such as small projects that are never more than 1/4" steel and the type and size of welders you will be using.

I suggest you try and Google or find a copy of NEC 630 and do a little reading before determining your service size to your building.

Good luck.